# subject of a to-infinitive

Tags: infinitives

Consider this sentence, please:

> He's taking her ***to see*** the fireworks.

What is the subject of the to-infinitive? Is it *her* or *[h]e and her both*?

Comment: Most likely if he was *taking her to see the **gynecologist*** it would be just "Her", but if he was *taking her to see the **latest blockbuster movie*** it would be "He and her both". In short, the ***syntax*** says nothing about the "inclusivity" of the verb ***to see*** here.

Comment: ...plus it's still the same superficial structure in *He's taking **her to eat** after the movie* and *He's taking **a sandwich** to eat after the movie.* Context and pragmatism, is all.

Comment: Note that 'subject' etc are syntactically defined; 'agent' etc are defined by the meaning involved. Contrast _John kicked the ball_ (S - V - DO) with the passivised form _The ball was kicked by John_ (S - V - by-phrase). The subject is different, but the agent ('doer') is John in each sentence.

Comment: Thanks for the useful comments.@FumbleFingers, can I interpret your second sentence "He's taking a sandwich to eat after the movie" as "He's taking a sandwich that he can eat after the movie."

Comment: Do infinitives even have subjects?